# How to set a private variable value without a setter?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, access-modifiers

I am currently doing a unit testing assignment.
Within the project I have a Bank Account Class and a UnitTesting class.
Within the BankAccount class we have a variable
`private double balance { get; }`

With a variable of private  type and only get, how do I update the balance once I've done through a class function of withdrawing cash for example.

```
public double Debit (double amount)
        /*Ensuring Debit Amount is Valid and Balance Available for Transaction*/
        {
            IsAmountVerified(amount);     
            if (IsAmountVerified(amount) is false) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("",WRONG_AMOUNT); }
            if (balance < amount) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("",INSUFFICIENT_BALANCE); }
            else **balance -= amount**;
        /*Return Value*/
            return amount;
        }
```

How do I update the balance? Also making this variable private I cannot access it within the UnitTesting Class.

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void DepositTest1()
        {
            BankAccount Account = new BankAccount(100, "Baldip Singh");
            Account.Deposit(1);
            Assert.AreEqual(101, Account.balance);
        }
```

Thanks for any insight, cheers.

Comment: You can't write to a read-only property, silly. You might be able to write to its backing field, assuming it has one (not all properties do... e.g. what if the balance is the sum of something else?) To do that you'd have to reverse engineer the system under test.

Comment: Exactly! I am coming to the conclusion this may be an error in writing out the assignment -_-

Comment: You need to add `set;` to the property if you wish to alter it outside of the constructor.

Comment: `Within the BankAccount class we have a variable` You have a _property_.

Comment: Thanks for the correction mjwills trying to upvote it but I'm new to this platform.

Comment: @mjwillis or possibly `{get; init; }` (on more recent runtimes) - which changes fewer invariants about how the code will typically behave at runtime

Comment: Important note for @Baldeep - `double` is wholely unsuitable for monetary amounts; use `decimal` instead, if you don't want awkward conversations with your finance folks

Answer (score 1):

To support that *specific* scenario, a trick that many tools (serializers, etc) use is to look for a known auto-prop pattern of a field named `<{propertyName}>k__BackingField`, for example:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private readonly double <balance>k__BackingField;
```

You can access that via reflection (`GetField(...)` on the `Type`, specifying a `BindingFlags` that includes non-public and instance, then `SetValue(...)`). However, this won't work for manually implemented backing fields, or properties that don't *have* 1:1 relationships with backing fields, for example:

```cs
private double balance => 42;
```

In general, however, I would say: use the API surface that you're actually given. If the given API doesn't do what you need: *change/extend the API*, rather than subverting it. For example, you could add a setter:

```cs
// note I've changed the type, name, and accessibility here!
public decimal Balance { get; private set; }
```

(you could also look at `init` instead of `set`)

Answer (score 0):

Get only auto-implemented properties are immutable (except within the constructor).  To declare a get-only property that returns the value of a private field variable use:

```
private double _balance;
private double balance => _balance;
```

Comment: `balance` would be better as `Balance`.

Comment: Immutability is a lie (unless you're executing on a ROM or specialized hardened systems) - as is accessibility. Nothing is truly immutable or inaccessible, if you try hard enough :)

Answer (score 0):

If your business scenario requires updating balance you need to add private setter for that property ( in case to allow updating only inside your class), otherwise your business scenario just won’t work.

If you want to get the values from private fields, you can add public getter-properties or public methods that return needed values.

In your case I would suggest change your logic like this:
public double Balance {get; private set;}